# Solr Snowball stemmer is inconsistent with Spanish

Tags: solr, stemming, porter-stemmer

I have this stemmed field:

```
<fieldtype name="textes" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords-es.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish" protected="protwords-es.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish" protected="protwords-es.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

The expected result of the search query `alquileres` (rents) would be a match of `alquiler` (rent). But when I go to "Field Analysis" in the Solr Admin site, and check an index value of `alquiler` and a query value of `alquileres`, the following happens:

- When indexing `alquiler`, it gets stemmed into `alquil`.
- When querying `alquileres`, it gets stemmed into  `alquiler`.

So the simple case of searching the plural form of a word (`alquileres`) would not match its singular form (`alquiler`).

Shouldn't both the index and the query be stemmed into the same stem (either `alquiler` or `alquil`)? Is this a limitation of the algorithm or a misunderstanding/misconfiguration from my part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowball stemming is very limited... You'd get better result by using a dictionary (Hunspell stemmer) : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Hunspell

Comment: Didn't know about that. I'll definitely take a look a it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried Hunspell, but it suffers from the same malfunction. `alquileres` keeps stemming into `alquiler`, and `alquiler` into `alquil`. My kingdom for a decent Spanish stemmer!

Comment: Could you try `solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory` ?

Comment: @Chewie I'm having the same problem with variations of "enfermería", did you find a solution or just turned off stemming?

Answer (score 0):

I use hunspell from openoffice and it does an excelent job.

My example:

```
URL-Elastic/_analyze?analyzer=es_AR&text=alquileres
```

And return:

```
{
  tokens:
  [
    {
      token: "alquiler",
      start_offset: 0,
      end_offset: 10,
      type: "<ALPHANUM>",
      position: 1
    }
  ]

}
```

Link: https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html